# Does convergence of arithmetic mean imply convergence of geometric mean?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, means

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of positive real numbers, which is not convergent. ($x_n$ does not converge to a finite number, nor to infinity). Define

$$ A_n = \frac{x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_n}{n} \quad \text{ and }\quad G_n = \sqrt[n]{x_1x_2...x_n}.$$

> Does the convergence of $A_n$ imply the convergence of $G_n$ or vice versa?

I know that if $x_n \to L \in \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$, then both $A_n,G_n$ converge to $L$. But here I assume $x_n$ is not convergent.

I also wonder if adding a boundedness assumption on $x_n$ changes anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a partial negative answer. Consider
$$a_n = \begin{cases} n & \text{if $n$ is odd}, \\ \frac{1}{n-1} & \text{if $n$ is even}. \end{cases}$$
Then
$$A_n \geq \frac{\frac{(n+1)^2}{4}}{n} \to \infty,$$
but
$$G_n = \begin{cases} \sqrt[n]{n} & \text{if $n$ is odd}, \\ 1 & \text{if $n$ is even} \end{cases} \to 1.$$
Also note that even if both limits exist, they do not need to be equal. This is easily seen by something simple such as $a_n = 2 + (-1)^n$.

Comment: The question was whether the convergence of $A_n$ implies the convergence of $G_n$.

Comment: @quasi "or vice versa". OP asked multiple questions and this answers one of them, which is why it is obviously just a partial answer.

Comment: Apologies, I missed the "or vice versa".

Comment: @Klaus Thanks for this great answer. I particularly liked the observation regarding the $2+(-1)^n$. Very cool.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to show that the convergence of $A_n$ does not imply the convergence of $G_n$.

Let $\mathbb{N}_0$ denote the set of nonnegative integers, and let
$S=\{2^k{\,\mid\,}k\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$.

Let the sequence $x_1,x_2,x_3,...$ be defined by
$$
x_n=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{2^n}}}&\text{if}\;n\in S\\[4pt]
1&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Then the sequence $(x_n)$ is a bounded, non-convergent sequence of positive real numbers.

For $A_n$ we have
$$
\frac{n-\bigl(\log_2(n)+1\bigr)}{n} < A_n < 1
$$
hence ${\displaystyle{\lim_{n\to\infty}}}A_n=1$.

For $G_n$ we have
$$
G_n
=
\begin{cases}
{\large{\frac{1}{2}}}&\text{if}\;n+1\in S\\[4pt]
{\Large{\frac{{\Large{1}}}{2^{\left(2-{\large{\frac{1}{n}}}\right)}}}}&\text{if}\;n\in S\\
\end{cases}
$$
hence the sequence $(G_n)$ has limit points ${\large{\frac{1}{2}}}$ and ${\large{\frac{1}{4}}}$, so $(G_n)$ is non-convergent.

Comment: Thanks! That is a very nice answer. According to my computation, $G_n=\frac{1}{2^{\frac{2^k-2}{2^k-1}}}$, where $n+1=2^k \in S$. And also for $n \in S$, it should be $2-2/n$ instead of $2-1/n$. This doesn't change this great answer. Thanks.

Comment: I summarize the idea for myself: Most of the sequence are $1$'s. Thus adding a "few" exceptions" does not change the asymptotic behavior of the arithmetic average. However, it does create "spikes" or "bug jumps" in the geometric average, when passing from $n \in S$ to $n+1 \in S$, thus creating multiple limit points. Brilliant idea.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple counterexample is $x_n=-1$. Then $A_n=-1$ is convergent but $G_n=(-1)^n$ and does not converge. Moreover this shows that the convergence of $x_n$ does not imply that of $G_n$.

Comment: Yes, but I required the $x_i$ to be positive in my question...